# connectionDidFinishLoading without calling didReceiveData?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm doing a simple WISPr client. When I testing it using `BTOpenZone` hotspot, I found that `willSendRequest` is called and it will redirect me to the hotspot landing page. 
I return nil in `willSendRequest` because i wish to get the WISPr xml tag, but i found that the `connectionDidFinishLoading` is called, and i check there is no data received.

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)redirectResponse;
    int statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
    NSLog(@"redirect status code : %d", statusCode);

    NSDictionary *dict = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];
    NSLog(@"redirect dict : %@", [dict description]);

    if (statusCode >= 300 && statusCode < 400)
    {
    NSLog(@"redirect requested:  %@", request);
        return NULL;
    }
    return request;
}
```

Even i use the tcpdump to sniff the packet, i also can't find any WISPr tag.

Any ideas why there is no WISPr xml tag?

I really appreciate helps from you guys. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be returning nil from

`webView:resource:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:fromDataSource:`

The tags you need should be contained in the NSURLResponse parameter of that method (which will actually be an NSHTTPURLResponse), and then you should return an HTTP POST request to the appropriate URL with the login credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me try first and will revert back for the status

Comment: Can you please edit the original question and post some of your actual code?

Comment: I just added in some codes and add in NSLog to print out the NSURLResponse as you suggest to see the result. Will feedback again once i manage to test it. Thx

Comment: hi, i have the logs:
redirect status code : 302
redirect dict : {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = close;
    Date = "Sat, 14 Jul 2012 13:00:45 GMT";
    Location = "https://www.btopenzone.com:8443/home?CPURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.msftncsi.com%2F";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
}
it still didn't show the WISPr tag :(